# I have installed elasticsearch, but how can I searched data from MySQL table by multiple input field's from multiple table columns

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have installed a **ElasticSearch**, but how can I search data from MySQL table by multiple input field's from multiple table columns

I have installed laravel 5.5 for a product searched project. I want to search data by product name, price and other from product table using **ElasticSearch** method. I have added to index all product data at first but how can I search data by dynamic data from my controller

Comment: The best way forward would be to make use of a package, such as: https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch

If not you would need to access the ElasticSearch data using it's API, which would require a lot of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can i used sql query in elasicsearch?

Comment: if(@$request->keyword){
 $result =  Products::where('name', 'like', $request->keyword);
}if(@$request->price){
 $result =  $result->whereBetween('price', 'like', [10,20]);
}
$result = $result->get();